# Javascript callbacks not firing in Cordova Android app

Tags: android, cordova, callback

I'm working on a Cordova Android app to receive push notifications.  The app has no problems except none of the Javascript callbacks get fired.  For example, in the code below, either successHandler or errorHandler should fire...but they don't.

```
function successHandler (result) { 
    alert('Success - ' + result); 
}

function errorHandler (error) {
    alert('Success - ' + result);
}

nNotification.register(successHandler, errorHandler, {"senderID":"abcdefghijklmnopn","ecb":"onNotificationGCM"});
```

The same is true for other Javascript cide sent from Java to the webview (like onNotificationGCM.)

What could be preventing all Javascript originating from Java from being fired?

Comment: Do you test on real device. On emulator( defaul), yo can't use GCM, because it not include google service.

Comment: Yes, I am testing on an actual device and not using the emulator.

Comment: Does device ready and plugin import correct. If all correct, can you post onNotificationGCM function, make sure onNotificationGCM is global function on window object.

Answer (score 0):

After succesfull registration with GCM you will get callback to onNotificationGCM function

({"senderID":"abcdefghijklmnopn","ecb":"**onNotificationGCM**"})
so, add

```
window. onNotificationGCM = function(msg){
  alert(JSON.stringify(msg))

}
```

you wil get callback , if GCM register fail occur you will not get any callback.

If you need to get callback on successHandler function you need to edit some java files

**1.GCMBaseIntentService.java**

replace `PushPlugin.sendJavascript( json );`

with `PushPlugin.sendOnregisterSuccess( json );`

**2.PushPlugin.java**

Add one public variable

```
public static CallbackContext cal= null;
```

and inside

```
public boolean execute(String action, JSONArray data, CallbackContext callbackContext)
```

function add

```
 cal = callbackContext;
```

And add new private function inside **PushPlugin** class

```
public static void sendOnregisterSuccess(JSONObject _json) {
        //String _d = "javascript:" + gECB + "(" + _json.toString() + ")";
        //Log.v(TAG, "sendJavascript: " + _d);
        cal.success(_json);

    }
```

Now you will get registration successCallback  in **successHandler** function